# SQL Server - Dropped table but unused space is not reclaimed?

Tags: sql-server

The most common variation of this question that I've seen is that people deleted rows and/or columns but the size didn't decrease, and most of the replies in response to this question is that you shouldn't try to shrink your database if you can help it. From what I've read, the best way to handle this is to insert the contents into a new table which would allow SQL to neatly compile the data.

I'm not sure if what I'm about to say is the same thing, but I deleted several large, unused ***tables*** from my database that should have freed up some space, but it seems like it did absolutely nothing. I started out with 14GB in size, and after deletion, I still have 14GB in size.

Here's a snapshot of what it looks like after deletion:

```
FileSizeMB  UsedSpaceMB UnusedSpaceMB   Type    DBFileName
285.06      8.94          276.13        Log     Database_DB_log
13866.00    9160.88       4705.13       Data    Database_DB
14151.06    9169.82       4981.26               *** Total for all files ***
```

The script can be found here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61762

From this summary, it definitely looks like I've got some unused space that's from the tables I just deleted, but is there a way to reclaim it without doing a shrink? I'm just very uncomfortable doing a shrink because of all the bad things I've read about it, and given I've never dealt with indexes in SQL, I'm not confident that I will be able to re-index properly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have it set to automatically shrink, which I would doubt, then you need to shrink the files.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190757(v=sql.120).aspx) explains the process and the pros/cons.

Shrinking is not inherently bad, it just depends on your use case. If you're going to shrink the DB in order to grow it again very quickly then I'd say "why bother?", but if it gives you needed space and you don't think it'll grow fast then you're probably fine.

Comment: I have a question that I don't think I completely understood from the link: "A shrink operation does not preserve the fragmentation state of indexes in the database, and generally increases fragmentation to a degree. This is another reason not to repeatedly shrink the database." If I were to shrink database, but on the shrink action section, left the "Reorganize Files" check box blank - would that still cause fragmentation?

Comment: I believe it would. What you'd probably want to do is an index re-org after the shrink operation is complete. That's an online operation (better that way than a rebuild on anything but Enterprise) but can be intensive so might cause high queueing and the like.

Comment: Before you go randomly shrinking your database you should read this article and all the articles referenced inside. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/ And here is a really good one about using auto-shrink. http://serverfault.com/questions/20909/is-it-safe-to-have-sql-server-auto-shrink-turned-on